# ASP source code and database in 2 different remote servers

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, ado

I have hosted my website. But I do not have database privileges. Since i want to include CONTACT form in my website, I had created an asp page in my server (A) and created mysql database in another web server B(with the help of a friend who has created a db in her domain)

register.asp (resides in A)

```
<!--#include virtual="http://some_server_name.com/connect.asp"-->


connect.asp (resides in B)

Dim con_project
Dim connstring
set con_project = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ConnString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER='host ipaddress';Port=3306; DATABASE='db_name'; " &_
"UID='uname';PASSWORD='pwd'; OPTION=3;"
```

When I run the asp file , I get this error msg.

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC
>   Drivers error '80004005'
>
> [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Client does
>   not support authentication protocol
>   requested by server; consider
>   upgrading MySQL client
>
> /wah/includes/connect.asp, line 34

any help?
any help?

Answer (score 0):

What it's saying is basically the client does not support the type of authentication you use.

I am not sure why you would use **server** attributes on your connection string since your **connect.asp** reside in the same server as your database. Care to explain this?

Please try if this work:

```
Dim con_project
set con_project = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con_project.Provider="MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver"
con_project.Open "c:/webdata/northwind.mdb"
```